# Plupload & jQuery not working in IE

Tags: jquery, plupload

Plupload is working in all browsers bar IE. The file browser doesn't open upon pressing the `#photo-upload` link in IE. The instance of `uploader` is definately created properly- checked with Dev tools.

Many thanks for any solutions!

**This is the script we're using to create the uploader:**

```
        var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
            runtimes : 'gears,html5,flash,silverlight,html4',
            browse_button : 'photo-upload',
            container : 'img-container',
            url : 'productPhoto.php?id=<?=$_GET["id"];?>',
            max_file_size : '5mb',
            flash_swf_url : '/dev/plupload/js/plupload.flash.swf',
            silverlight_xap_url : '/dev/plupload/js/plupload.silverlight.xap',
            unique_names : true,
            filters : [{title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"}],
            multipart_params: {type:1},

            // Post init events, bound after the internal events
            init : {
                UploadProgress: function(up, file) {
                    // Called while a file is being uploaded
                    $("#bar").css("width",file.percent+"%");
                },
                FilesAdded: function(up, files) {
                    $(".progress").slideDown();
                    uploader.start();
                    up.refresh(); // Reposition Flash/Silverlight
                },
                UploadComplete: function(up, file, info) {
                    // Called when a file has finished uploading
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $(".progress").slideUp();
                        $("#bar").css("width","0");
                        document.location.reload();
                    },2000);
                },
                Error: function(up, args) {
                    // Called when a error has occured
                    alert(args);
                    up.refresh(); // Reposition Flash/Silverlight
                }
            }
        });
        uploader.init();
```

Comment: Do any errors occur? your code looks fine. Where is the `#photo-upload` html and binding method?

Comment: No errors, seems to be purely the binding of Plupload's `browse_button`.

Comment: is this code located above or below html declaration of your button ?
Does this code execute on $(document).ready ?

Comment: At the bottom of the page. The code initialises fine (the Flash runtime is created properly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An issue with the fact that the link is inside a dropdown- hidden at start. The link must be visible.

Comment: +1. Thanks for sharing your solution, Nick, it solved the same problem for me. I had the container's `display` property set to `none` at page load, which caused plupload's browse button to not work.

Comment: Glad you found this helpful @MariusSchulz!

Comment: Thank you @NickPrice, you've just saved hours of debugging for me

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest to avoid placing your upload control inside the container which is hidden.

```
<div class="container" style="display:none">
    <a id="pickfiles" href="#">[Select files]</a>
    <a id="uploadfiles" href="#">[Upload files]</a>
</div>
```

In above example, container div has a style element stating `display:none` property. That is the reason it won't work in IE.

Just change it to `display:block` or remove the style element and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with hiding the plupload div upon page load in IE 8.  Instead of display:none, I chose to absolutely position the div off the screen, then when needed, pass in new top/left coordinates:

```
    #plupload {
        display: block;
        position:absolute;
        top:-999px;
        left:-999px;
        background:#fff;
        border:1px solid #c8c8c8;
        padding:10px;
        z-index: 951;
    }

    $('#some-button-to-open-plupload-widget').button().click(function() {
         var css = {"top":"175px", "left":"175px"};
         $("#plupload").css(css);
    });

    $('#some-button-to-close-plupload-widget').button().click(function() {
         var css = {"top":"-999px", "left":"-999px"};
         $("#plupload").css(css);
    });

    <div id="plupload">
       <a href="" class="ui-icon ui-icon-close" id="close"></a>
       <div id="uploader" style="display:block">
           <p>Your browser doesn't have Flash, Silverlight or HTML5 support.</p>
       </div>    
    </div>
```